# DataTables abrir un modal cuando le das click a una fila de la tabla

Tags: laravel, datatables, livewire

me gustaría aprender como poder mostrar un modal con la información del registro cuando le das click a su fila en una tabla construida con DataTables, pudiera hacer esto creando una columna con un boton pero que que quiero lograr es al dar click en la fila. Estoy usando laravel y la vista es un componente de pantalla completa de Livewire.

Hasta el momento tengo:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#accounts').DataTable({
            language: {
                url: "{{ asset('asset/admin/plugins/DataTables/lang/' . app()->getLocale() . '.json') }}"
            },
            lengthMenu: [
                [10, 25, 50, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, "All"]
            ],
            autoWidth: false,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('datatables.accounts') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id'},
                {data: 'username'},
                {data: 'email'},
                {data: 'joindate'},
                {data: 'last_ip'},
                {data: 'last_login'},
            ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML de la tabla

```
<table class="table card-table table-vcenter datatable display nowrap" id="accounts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Join Date</th>
            <th>Last IP</th>
            <th>Last Login</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div class="d-none" id="modal">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" for="username">Nombre de Usuario</label>
            <div class="input-icon mb-3">
                <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" wire:model="username" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En el modal hay muchos mas campos lo que solo mostré acá uno solo

Comment: Prueba con algo así: `$('#accounts').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () { //codigo aqui })`

Comment: era lo que estaba probando ahora mismo pero me surgió otra duda que publique en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558658/llamar-un-m%c3%a9todo-de-un-componente-de-livewire-desde-javascript, ya que allá dentro necesitaba llamar a un método del componente, porque así solo puedo mostrar los detalles de los campos que tengo en la tabla y deseo mostrar muchos mas campos de los que se muestran en la tabla

Comment: pero usando DataTables no hay forma de realizar esta operación, esta es una duda que tengo