# Llamar un método de un componente de livewire desde javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, livewire

Estoy intentando llamar a un metodo de un componente de livewire desde una vista usando javascript pero asta el momento no he logrado que me funcione.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#accounts').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(e) {
            Livewire.emit('showAccount, this.childNodes[0].innerText');
            $('#modal').removeClass('d-none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controlador del componente

```
class AccountController extends Component
{
    public $username;
    public $account_id;

    protected $listeners = ['showAccount' => 'showAccount'];

    public function render()
    {        
        return view('Themes.admin.views.account.account');
    }

    public function showAccount(Account $account)
    {
        $this->account_id = $account->id;
        $this->username = $account->username;
    }
}
```

Al realizar Livewire.emit('showAccount, this.childNodes[0].innerText'); no llama al método showAccount del componente. Que pudiera estar asiendo mal.

Comment: Eso que pones así: `this.childNodes[0].innerText`  quizás deberia ser más bien así: `e.target.childNodes[0].innerText`

Comment: ya lo cambie pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Si eso del Livewire son dos parámetros creo que deberian estar escritos así: `Livewire.emit('showAccount', e.target.childNodes[0].innerText);`

Comment: pero no llama al método showAccount

Comment: modifique el método para que estuviera mas sencillo solo para probar si llama o no al método, para llamarlo asi Livewire.emit('showAccount'); y no funciona

Comment: ya lo logre me faltaba protected $listeners = ['showAccount' => 'showAccount']; en el controlador que lo había quitado asiendo pruebas

Comment: me alegro, porque no tenia ni idea del livewire y estaba mirando su funcionamiento justo ahora :-)  Saludos!

Comment: lo que pude ver que si usaba e.target.childNodes[0].innerText llegaba al metodo como null y al usar this.childNodes[0].innerText si me llegaba el valor

Answer (score 0):

Tenia el mismo problema por un componente, no se si te sirva aun pero tu código quedaría así

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#accounts').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(e) {
        @this.emit('showAccount, this.childNodes[0].innerText');
        $('#modal').removeClass('d-none');
    });
});
```

Saludos.